# iptables not dropping udp port for exact ip address

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

My iptables rules are as follows:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N f2b
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b
-A INPUT -d (my public facing ip)/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 10000 -j DROP
-A f2b -s 1.1.1.1/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b -j RETURN
```

All other tables also have every chain on ACCEPT.
Why is 1.1.1.1 not able to access tcp port 80 and 443, but everyone is still able to access port 10000 on my public ip?

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. The title suggests that you want to drop specific traffic (be EXACT!) and the body asks why is something else rejected. Instead of poking around write what is your goal, what you've done to achieve it and what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b
```

Says if goto a chain named **f2b**

```
-A f2b -s 1.1.1.1/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

The first rule in the chain named **f2b** say REJECT  1.1.1.1/32

As far as 8.8.8.8 goes, I can't see the traffic maybe its using TCP and not UDP.  The 8.8.8.8 is a destination, so if the source was 8.8.8.8 and the destination something else then it wouldn't match the rule.

Try this:

```
-I FORWARD 1 -d 8.8.8.8/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 10000 -j DROP
```

Comment: Ah i totally overlooked that part in my post, 8.8.8.8 is meant to be my public facing ipv4 address, that's why i use `-d`. I still tried your suggestion but it didn't work sadly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block traffic that comes ***from*** 8.8.8.8 from hitting your port, you use `-s` (source address) and not `-d` (destination address)